# prometheus metric failed when add process metric

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, prometheus, open-telemetry

I am adding metric to my project.
I am using OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.Process package, but when I check the Targets status in Prometheus , I saw the following error:

> unit "seconds" not a suffix of metric "process_cpu_time_seconds_total"

[image]

here is how I add the metrics

```
.WithMetrics(x =>
        {
            x.AddProcessInstrumentation();
            x.AddHttpClientInstrumentation();
            x.AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation();
            //x.AddRuntimeInstrumentation();
            x.AddPrometheusExporter()
                .AddMeter("MyApplication.Api")
                .AddMeter("System.Runtime")
                .AddMeter("System.Net.Http")
                .AddMeter("System.Data.SqlClient")
                .AddMeter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting")
                .AddMeter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel")
                .AddMeter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections")
                .AddMeter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing")
                .AddMeter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics")
                .AddMeter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.RateLimiting");
        });
```

Comment: Can you show what the actual metrics page gives (only related to this metric part, please)?

Comment: Also, I believe `promtool` gives a bit more extended reason of error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - in my case I used

```
endpoints.MapPrometheusScrapingEndpoint()
```

And it got fixed after I changed it to

```
app.UseMetricServer();
```